# How many devices can be hooked up to one PC Bluetooth adapter at a time?

Tags: bluetooth

I'd like to buy a bluetooth adapter to hook up game-console controllers to my PC. However, I need to know if I can play 4-player games with 4 controllers using only one adapter, or if I need to buy four.

The Internet is filled with conflicting information:

- All Bluetooth adapters can support 7 devices, period. *([source](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2576415/controllers-devices-connect-single-bluetooth-dongle.html#15504131))*
- You can hook up 7 devices, but only if they're all different types of devices. *([source](http://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx19Y4PCK3Z48I4/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B007Q45EF4#cmQAListItemAnswer_Mx14KIIK24KBEXV))*
- You can hook up unlimited devices, no restrictions. *([source](http://www.amazon.com/forum/-/Tx19Y4PCK3Z48I4/ref=ask_dp_dpmw_al_hza?asin=B007Q45EF4#cdPostContentBox_Mx2MPZT6M0QY56P) - a Bluetooth Dongle tech-support)*
- Only devices that support "multipoint functionality" can have multiple hooked up at once, and the choice of adapter doesn't make a difference.  *([source](http://www.amazon.com/many-devices-connect-same-time/forum/FxAIC993VT4D9G/TxA4EDA4EY32B8/1/ref=cm_cd_ql_tlc_al?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00DJ83070#cmQAListItemAnswer_Mx2ZHYWP5K695JN))*
- Only Bluetooth 4.1 adapters support multiple devices. *([source](http://www.amazon.com/many-devices-connect-same-time/forum/FxAIC993VT4D9G/TxA4EDA4EY32B8/1/ref=cm_cd_ql_tlc_al?_encoding=UTF8&asin=B00DJ83070#cdPostContentBox_Mx2B4BO5JTRSS3O))*
- You can only use one device per Bluetooth adapter. *([source](http://www.reddit.com/r/PS3/comments/kimp3/4_ps3_controllers_wirelessly_on_a_pc/c2kn40a))*

So, **can I I hook up multiple controllers or not?**  Also, can I hook up *(say)* two PS3 and two PS4 simultaneously?

Please answer with credible sources, to distinguish from all the above hearsay.

Comment: I don't know a thing about original XBOX controllers (that is, not XBOX 360 or XBOX ONE), but XB360 and XB1 controllers don't use Bluetooth, but a proprietary wireless protocol, and thus require purchasing a [Xbox 360 Wireless Gaming Receiver for Windows](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-other-devices/windows/xbox-360-wireless-gaming-receiver-windows) for 360 controller (allows up to 4 devices), or not-yet-released (but announced) adapter for Xbox One controller. I have no idea about PS3 controllers though.

Comment: @miroxlav: This is primarily a question about what Bluetooth adapters support, the fact that I'm interested in pairing them with controllers specifically is secondary.  So no, this is the correct site.

Comment: [This article](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller) should be interesting for you. It also states: "The drivers support 4 DS3s connected by USB or via Bluetooth (one dongle can support **4 DS3 connections**)". It seems like the real limit is in the PC driver, which might explain the mixed results you have found.

Comment: It depends on the controller and Bluetooth specification version. It also depends on your operating system, drivers, the adapter itself and too many things to even start thinking about it.

Comment: Does anyone know if a keyboard and mouse can be connected through 1 Bluetooth adapter and used at the same time?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The internet is filled with conflicting information because a lot of it applies to different scenarios.

### General background:

1. Firstly, there's a *paired* device and a *connected* device and then an *actively communicating* device. Your links above confuse these and no distinction, but there is a difference in functionality. A device can be paired, but not connected. Similarly, it can be connected but not transmitting. Think of a paired device as a saved wireless network that you're not connected to.
2. Then there are host devices and client devices. This is a generalization, but consider PCs, mobile phones, and tablets (and consoles) to be hosts, and headsets, controllers, mice, keyboards, etc. to be clients.
3. Then there's *profiles*, a profile indicating a type of connection (e.g. audio, HID, etc.)

---

**With that in mind, the following apply:**

In general, *host* devices support up to 7 simultaneously **connected** devices and a practically unlimited number of **paired**. Host devices are like a wireless router - you can connect many different devices at a time.

*Client* devices typically support a *limited* number of pairings, anywhere between 1 and 5, and only *one single* *connection*. They act like a wireless client - you can save many different networks but only connect to one at a time.

Some *profiles* only support one connection at a time on some devices - for example, some Bluetooth speakers can only connect to one computer at a time. A phone for example usually can only connect to one HSP (headset) at a time but can connect multiple HIDs (keyboards, mice, etc.).

---

**Also, to explain/clarify some of your links/references:**

- All Bluetooth adapters can support 7 devices, period.

**Mostly true** - the standards only allow up to seven *simultaneous connections* on a normal device. But you can *pair* any number of devices.

- You can hook up 7 devices, but only if they're all different types of
  devices.

**False**, but in some scenarios, you cannot simultaneously use two devices with the same *Bluetooth profile*. This generally applies to audio devices only (i.e. headsets) which may be all that some people are familiar with. For example, a phone can connect to one headset, or one music stream, or one of each, but not two headsets or two speakers. A PC can, however, connect to many phones at a time.

- You can hook up unlimited devices, no restrictions. (source - a Bluetooth Dongle tech-support)

**False**. You can usually *pair* unlimited devices on a *host*, but you cannot connect to them all simultaneously (again, think of the number of saved wireless networks, that aren't all connected at the same time)

- Only devices that support "multipoint functionality" can have multiple hooked up at once, and the choice of adapter doesn't make a difference.

**Partly true**. This only applies to *client* devices, such as headsets, controllers, keyboards, etc.. These limited devices can only connect to one host at a time if they do not have multipoint. A host can accept multiple clients even if those clients do not support multipoint.

- Only Bluetooth 4.1 adapters support multiple devices.

**False**. No idea where he got this from, it's plain rubbish.

- You can only use one device per Bluetooth adapter.

**False**. Pretty much everything in that entire statement is wrong.

So the final answer is yes, you can connect four controllers (clients) to one adapter (host) at a time. Even without the above information, it's fairly obvious as per @oldmud0's answer,

> if [controller] uses Bluetooth, then how does the PlayStation establish a
>   connection to all 4 controllers with a single radio [if Bluetooth didn't support it]?

Comment: This is lots of great information, and all *sounds* correct; but do you have any references to back it all up?

Comment: I've marked this as correct because it all _appears_ to be correct, but I can't award it the bounty since you never gave any references.

Comment: How does that could work (see link)? https://www.polar.com/en/club .It seems they have up to 20 devices on a single ipad. Is the app connecting and disconnecting people every couple seconds?

Comment: Is the limit of `7` still true for Bluetooth LE (i.e. Bluetooth 4 and 5) ? Under "Bluetooth Basic Rate/Enhanced Data Rate technology" the wikipedia page has a `7` for "Active slaves", while under "Bluetooth Low Energy technology" it has: "Not defined; implementation dependent".

Comment: Yet one cannot listen to audio on Windows 10 via two Bluetooth headsets?  For example, my Sony WH-1000XM2 will always override (i.e. prevent it from being heard) my V-MODA Forza even though they are both connected (as opposed to only paired).

Comment: @zylstra you're getting into the OS & application layer. BLE is a low-level communication protocol. What software does with that connection (beyond profile information) is not part of it.

Answer (score 15):

Before I begin answering the question, think about this: if DualShock uses Bluetooth, then *how does the PlayStation establish a connection to all 4 controllers with a single radio*?

I use [Scarlet.Crush's SCP drivers](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller), and they seem to have great Bluetooth support (I use regular USB).

They require sacrificing one Bluetooth dongle to install SCP drivers on it, which replace the original Bluetooth drivers/stack (meaning the dongle will be dedicated to connecting DualShock controllers and nothing more).

The fact that plural in "controllers" is used frequently in the documentation confirms that you are able to connect all four controllers into a single dongle.

Due to the controller's hardware limitations (4 lights) and SCP's own limitations as a result, you can only have up to four controllers connected at once.

[image: Only 4 pads allowed!]

Since a concurrent connection to 4 devices are supported by a majority of Bluetooth radios (the forum post above lists them out) and this does not even come near to the spec's hard limit of 7, there is no doubt you will be able to connect all 4 controllers with a single dongle, regardless of whether they are DS3 or DS4, given that everything is correctly configured and paired up.

Comment: Can confirm that I was able to use four PS3 controllers at once (I've since sold two off) with the SCP drivers.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is much more complex than a single answer.

There are many different types of Bluetooth connections, not all of these connections are interchangeable.

It also depends heavily upon which version of Bluetooth is being used in the devices, both the reciever for the PC and the controller.

As you can see from the Bluetooth 4.2 specification, which is 2,772 pages, it is quite complex.

Bluetooth 4.2 specification document:

https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=286439

I doubt a definitive answer can be given to this question as to all Bluetooth devices in all scenarios.

I would however in this case as it's quite a simple scenario, purchase a single Bluetooth adapter and try to connect four controllers. I suspect that it will work from what I have deduced from the Bluetooth specification but I would ensure that you purchase a 4.2 Bluetooth adapter.

**Apple Website FAQ**

> The official Bluetooth specifications state seven is the maximum number of Bluetooth devices that can be connected at once. However, three to four devices is a practical limit, depending on the types of devices and profiles are used. Some devices require more Bluetooth data, so they are more demanding than other devices. Data-intensive devices may reduce the total number of devices that can be active at the same time. If a Bluetooth device becomes slow to connect or does not perform reliably, reduce the total number of connected devices.

[Apple Website Bluetooth FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201171)

As can be seen from the official Apple website they state that the maximum number of connected devices is 7. The official Bluetooth spec says that up to 255 sleeping devices can be connected. This would indicate that the maximum number of parallel active connections is 7, however due to the complexity of the connections and amount of data to be transferred in most scenarios the practical limit is 3 or 4. Bluetooth signal can also be effected largely by other household devices such as Wifi, Microwaves and Household Phones. A true answer to this would be difficult to come by in relation to your exact scenario due to the large number of variables, however we can see that theoretically seven devices can have active connections in parallel and as reported by Apple the practical limit in the majority of scenarios is 3 or 4.

Comment: I personally disagree that an answer is by definition a definite answer, an answer to an obscure question will always be obscure. As will an over simplified question surrounding an extremely complex subject.

Comment: Just because the specification has a lot of pages, it doesn't mean the answer is complex, or that no one knows the answer.  Also I don't believe Bluetooth 4.2 devices are being sold yet.

Comment: I was just illustrating the complexity of the spec. If you have a read of how different devices can interact you can see its dependant on the type of device and how it connects, as well as whether the individual device is capable of interacting with other connected devices. If it isn't then I apologise and will rectify my answer now.

Comment: +1. I don't understand why this answer was downvoted. It contains the theoretical limit and the practical one by Apple. My addition: The variant of [Bluetooth Low Energy standard](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/BLE_-_FAQ) specifies "up to 3 simultaneous connections", so limits also vary by Bluetooth variant, besides other factors such as driver implementation ([example](http://forums.pcsx2.net/Thread-XInput-Wrapper-for-DS3-and-Play-com-USB-Dual-DS2-Controller) of driver limited to 4).

Comment: @harrymc - The answer didn't always include that information though.  I downvoted the original revision of the answer.