# Bluetooth transmitter and bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth

So am trying to achieve a silent disco for my daughter approx 35-40 children in a budget.
I am looking into buying 2-3 bluetooth transmitters and connecting each to their own laptop music source and getting bluetooth headphones of different colours to match each source .
Will be in an open hall so no signal barriers blocking or being an issue (well I think I'm not overly technical minded)

example So laptop 1 blue earphones connected/paired  to 1st bluetooth transmitter
Laptop 2 red earphones connected/paired to second bluetooth transmitter
Laptop 3 yellow ear phones connected / paired to third bluetooth transmitter

How many earphones maximum can I connect / pair up to each transmitting device ?
So the children will change coloured earphones rather than channels as in expensive headphones .
Hope this makes sense and someone is able to advise me

Comment: BT is complicated, but is easier once to learn the terminology......https://superuser.com/a/935508/40928

Answer (score 0):

Sounds exciting! In my experience, discoverable pairing of all the headsets to one laptop is doable, and that one laptop can be actively "connected" to multiple headsets at the same time. **But**, "Connected" only means system-connected. With your laptops, MacBook seems the way to go. Here's why:

**In Windows**, sending Audio through by selecting the Playback Device is limited to one headset, and deciding from the understandably long list of Bluetooth devices will be regrettably difficult as all get labelled the same, e.g. "H800 Logitech Headset". Some laptops can play to two bluetooth headsets at the same time by enabling Stereo Mix (unavailable on some laptops) then ″Listen to this device″ then selecting your second headset from the ″playback through this device″ menu. But that's only two concurrent headsets.

**For MAC**, you go to Utilities > Audio MIDI> Audio Devices where you can "create" a multi-outpt device by assigning all your paired bluetooth headsets.

Rick

Comment: Are you saying that on Mac it is technically possible to do what the OP is asking for? I have the same need and I don't own a Mac and I don't know if this feature has any kind of numeric limitations. Indeed, RIAA wouldn't be so happy about 30+ listeners of same audio stream

Comment: I also don't know if this is a hardware or software limitation, which means there could be a Linux-ish way to stream to multiple devices at same time